# Finding the leaf category in a table using recursive procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

Need to have all the leaf categories for a particular category.

For eg: i am having a table and data in that table as below

```
CREATE TABLE `world`.`category_table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` BIGINT(20) NULL,
  `sub_category_id` BIGINT(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));


insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (3267,4202);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (3267,4205);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (3267,4208);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4202,4203);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4202,4204);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4205,4206);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4205,4207);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4208,4209);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4208,4210);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4208,4453);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4208,4454);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4208,4457);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4208,4458);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4209,4452);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4210,4455);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4210,4456);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4458,4459);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4458,4460);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4458,4461);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4458,4462);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4458,4463);
insert into world.category_table (category_id, sub_category_id) values (4458,4464);
```

Now i want to have a leaf node for a particular category_id

```
for eg if i pass 3267 as input then output should be : 4203,4204,4206,4207,4452,4455,4456,4453,4454,4457,4459,4460,4461,4462,4463,4464,
```

I have written a procedure for this which is mentioned below

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetAllLeafCategories`(IN CATEGORYID BIGINT(20), INOUT RESULTSTRING longtext)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done int default 0;
    DECLARE SUBCATEGORYID BIGINT(20);
    DECLARE CATEGORY_CURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT SUB_CATEGORY_ID FROM world.category_table where category_id = CATEGORYID;
    DECLARE CONTINUE handler for not found SET done = 1;
    OPEN CATEGORY_CURSOR;
    SUBCATEGORYLOOP : LOOP
        FETCH CATEGORY_CURSOR INTO SUBCATEGORYID;
        IF done THEN
            if RESULTSTRING is null then 
                set RESULTSTRING = '';
            end if;
            SET RESULTSTRING = concat(RESULTSTRING, CATEGORYID, ',');
            LEAVE SUBCATEGORYLOOP;
        ELSE 
            SET CATEGORYID = SUBCATEGORYID;
            CALL GetAllLeafCategories(CATEGORYID, RESULTSTRING);
        END IF;
    END loop SUBCATEGORYLOOP;
     CLOSE CATEGORY_CURSOR;
END;
```

executed procedure with following input

```
set @RESULTSTRING = '';
call world.GetAllLeafCategories(3267, @RESULTSTRING);
select @RESULTSTRING;
```

i got output as follows : `4203,4204,4204,4206,4207,4207,4452,4452,4455,4456,4456,4453,4454,4457,4459,4460,4461,4462,4463,4464,4464,4458,4208,`

which is not correct output

can any one correct me or if possible can u provide a recursive procedure for this.

Comment: what is your version of mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are not using mysql 8.0, here is a solution for your need with just one query :

**MY SQL 5.7**

```
select 
  sub_category_id as leaf_id
from
  (
    select 
      * 
    from category_table
    order by category_id, sub_category_id
  ) products_sorted,
  (
    select @pv := '3267'
  ) initialisation
where find_in_set(category_id, @pv)
and length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', sub_category_id))
and sub_category_id not in (select  distinct category_id from category_table)
```

[**FIND A DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2d43b6667300de063d16b22b3c972849)

**IMPORTANT : Note that 5.7 solution will only work if category_id is always lower than sub_category_id, which seems to be your case.**

If you are using mysql 8.0, you could use recursive cte as follow :

**MY SQL 8.0**

```
with recursive cte (sub_category_id, category_id) as 
(
  select
    sub_category_id,
    category_id
  from category_table
  where category_id = 3267
  union all
  select
    ct.sub_category_id,
    ct.category_id
  from category_table ct
  inner join cte on ct.category_id = cte.sub_category_id
)
select sub_category_id as leaf_id 
from cte 
where sub_category_id not in (select distinct category_id from category_table)
```

[**FIND A SECOND DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5c8da346c081bc5e4d3976570c09750f)

Comment: you're welcome, do not forget to accept the answer if it solves your question ;)